# Sort label of a pie chart in a specific way

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, pie-chart, survey

I want to make a pie chart plot to display a survey result.
I'll try to keep it very simple.

On a question of my survey, there were several response type string, like this example :

Question :
"do you practice magic"

Possibles responses :
"yes", "not sure", "not intentionnally", "no"

Then I make a pie chart with the proportion of response in each type.
But on the pie chart, the response are sorted in a way that I don't want to :

[image]

What I want, in clockwise direction, from 0° (0° degree is at the 'right' of the circle if I'm right) :
'no', 'not sure', 'not intentionally', 'yes'.
For me, it require a specific sorting of index that I can't figure, because it's not alphabetical, not ascending, nothing, just "my" way.

For information the dataframe :

```
q1 : do you pratice magic ?
no                   6
not intentionally    2
not sure             1
yes                  3
dtype: int64
```

And if I list the index :

```
In : df2.index
Out: Index(['no', 'not intentionally', 'not sure', 'yes'], dtype='object', name='q1 : do you pratice magic ?')
```

And here is my code for the plot :

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6),dpi=60)
fig.suptitle(('Some title'),fontsize=20, fontweight='bold', **csfont)

#############################
ax = fig.add_subplot()
colors = iter(cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 4)))
label_font=18
startang=0
ax.pie(df2, 
        labels=df2.index,
        autopct='%1.0f%%',
        wedgeprops=dict(width=0.4, edgecolor="w",linewidth= 1, linestyle= '-', antialiased= True), 
        colors=colors, 
        startangle=startang, 
        textprops={'fontsize': label_font, **csfont}, 
        pctdistance=0.8, 
        labeldistance=1.15,
        )

ax.axis('equal')
##################
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear, I just find it !

just create a list of your specific order :

```
reorderindex = ['no', 'not sure', 'not intentionally', 'yes'.]
# the old one tocompare : ['no', 'not intentionally', 'not sure', 'yes']
```

and reindex with it :

```
df2 = df2.reindex(reorderindex)
```

Yolo !